# what is xmlns tag for xacro?

Tags: ros, urdf, sdf, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

what is xmlns tag for xacro?

Here is the tutorial of [xacro](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20Xacro%20to%20Clean%20Up%20a%20URDF%20File)

It is confusing for me to see the below code

```
<robot xmlns:sensor="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#sensor"
       xmlns:controller="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#controller"
       xmlns:interface="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#interface"
       xmlns:xacro="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#interface"
       name="pr2" >
```

Why linking to those paths?

When should I use this?

How should I write this?

I need a detailed explanation to it. I do not know what xmlns value I should assign to.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251816/what-is-xmlns-tag-for-xacro?/) by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 339 on 2017-01-12

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181888/what-does-xmlns-in-xml-mean, http://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/att_html_xmlns.asp

---

Originally posted by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) with karma: 1505 on 2017-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-12**:
This is basically the answer.

`xmlns` is short for "XML NameSpace", and is a special XML construct that is expained in the links @VictorLamoine posted. @shawnysh: you can essentially consider them like import statements in the example you posted. But it's really an XML thing, not ROS specific.

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on 2017-01-14**:
Thank @VictorLamoine and @gvdhoorn!!!